# Zend Paginator in Symfony (For Lucene Search Result)

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, symfony-1.4, zend-paginator

I've written the question in symfony forum, but got no result. Of course I know that people may be busy or unavailable so I can't have my answer right away. But I really needs this fast, so I posted here too. If this is not permitted somehow, please just close the question. Thanks.

Originally posted here:
http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=31537

Hi,
I have some question regarding using zend pagination in zend lucene. Checked the old forum, and found this: **forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=27342&p=103440&hilit=zend+pagination&sid=1cdc305c262c6b3cf79fdeef25761f34#p103440**
But I need some additional feature for that. I've tried the code in the post above, and it works. But how do we implement it in view?

Checking zend documentation, i create a view file in /web/view/scripts/pagination.php
with the code for the file found here:

**framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.paginator.usage.html**

With some modification for `$this->url()` to become `link_to()`
Then, the code in action looks like this:

```
$pager = Zend_Paginator::factory($query->execute()->getData());
$pager->setItemCountPerPage(3);
$pager->setCurrentPageNumber($request->getParameter('page', 1));
$pager->setDefaultScrollingStyle('Sliding');
Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('_pagination.php');

$this->pager = $pager;
```

And in view:
 `<?php echo $pager ?>`

The problem is, of course, is this the right thing to do?
Then, how can I get the current URL and modify its parameter in view? For zend, as I understands it, it's something like `$this->url(array('page', 5))`. Anyway to get this done in symfony?

Thanks before.

I've also check SO and get this:
**stackoverflow.com/questions/2002648/is-there-a-symfony-helper-for-getting-the-current-action-url-and-changing-one-or**

But I can't access $sf_request in the pagination.php mentioned above. I think it's because the pagination.php access Zend's front controller. And the strangest thing is, I can acess the default helper like UrlHelper (tried url_for and link_to - it works).

Ps. Sorry for the links in bold - can't post more than 1 link now.

Answer (score 0):

View scripts usually have a `.phtml` extension, not `.php`, that won't matter, but just so you know.

Try changing

```
$this->pager = $pager;
```

To

```
$this->view->pager = $pager;
```

Comment: Don't work :( It throws boatloads of errors. Thanks for the information about .phtml by the way.